# Adding multiple values to Enum Type variable

Tags: c#, enums

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

I refer a code from above link which is showing adding values to Enum Type.
but its not working at my end.
The code is expected output :
I am getting actual output:

Please refer code :
**
// Expected Output: Meeting days are Tuesday, Thursday, Friday

**// Actual Output: Meeting days are  Friday**

// Expected Output: Meeting days are Thursday, Friday

**// Actaul Output: Meeting days are Monday****

```
     class Program
{
    enum Days2
    {
        None = 1,
        Sunday = 2,
        Monday = 3,
        Tuesday = 4,
        Wednesday = 5,
        Thursday = 6,
        Friday = 7,
        Saturday = 8
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Days2 meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;

        // Initialize with two flags using bitwise OR.
        meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;

        // Set an additional flag using bitwise OR.
        meetingDays = meetingDays | Days2.Friday;


        Console.WriteLine("Meeting days are {0}", meetingDays);
        // Expected Output: Meeting days are Tuesday, Thursday, Friday
        **// Actual Output: Meeting days are  Friday**

        // Remove a flag using bitwise XOR.
        meetingDays = meetingDays ^ Days2.Tuesday;
        Console.WriteLine("Meeting days are {0}", meetingDays);

        // Expected Output: Meeting days are Thursday, Friday
        **// Actaul Output: Meeting days are Monday**

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you mark the enum with [Flags] attribute?

Comment: I think your question has been answered.

Comment: May be this example also? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386634/Select-multiple-enum-values-with-EnumFlagsSelector

Answer (score 13):

In order to be able to use bitwise operations to combine enum values, they need to have values that correspond to powers of two.

Additionally, you should mark the enum with the `Flags` attribute, and by convention use zero as "no flags set". Example:

```
[Flags]
public enum Days2 
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}
```

See the [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx#c87ff9e4-e1a8-4ab8-94e7-730db58ff2de) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Add [Flags] attribute to your enum.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use FlagsAttribute!

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Look at the value of `Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;` It should be 10. A bitwise AND is essentially an addition.

If you want several days, do them this way, binary style:

```
enum Days2
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64    
}
```

Or use the Flags attribute as others stated.

Comment: Looking at the Flags attribute definition... It's definitely a clean solution

Answer (score 1):

Mark the enum with `[Flags]` attribute.

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}
```