# How to express ordinal/cardinal directions that can be added together in C#?`

Tags: c#, enums

For a personal games project I am working on, I am wanting to implement 8-point movement for a character - a character can move North, North-East, East, South-East, etc.

After spending a few minutes trying to find ways to organize this setup to be mathematically convenient to code, I finally hit upon a winning setup - associating ordinal (NESW) directions to prime numbers greater than zero, one or two, and calculating cardinal directions (NE NW SE SW) from the sums of the two ordinals!

```
North: 3
Northeast: 10
East: 7
Southeast: 12
South: 5
Southwest: 14
West: 9
Northwest: 11
```

...One problem: I then tried to implement it in a C# `Enum`, which in [hindsight, and with some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858439/adding-multiple-values-to-enum-type-variable) I found to be a way that is not supported by C#.  Specifically:

```
public enum MotionDirection
{
    North = 3,
    NorthEast = 10,
    East = 7,
    SouthEast = 12,
    South = 5,
    SouthWest = 14,
    West = 9,
    NorthWest = 11
}

// ...SNIP...

MotionDirection direction;

float verticalDirection = ControlManager.GetAxis(VerticalAxis);
float horizontalDirection = ControlManager.GetAxis(HorizontalAxis);

if (verticalDirection > 0.0f)
    direction = MotionDirection.North;
else if (verticalDirection < 0.0f)
    direction = MotionDirection.South;

// Red-squigglies appear here, and they're well-earned.
if (horizontalDirection > 0.0f)
    direction += MotionDirection.East;
else
    direction += MotionDirection.West;
```

The reason I did it this was, was that I mis-remembered the concept of bitmasking, and thought that I could associate any integer to an Enum property without the `[Flags]` attribute, when in fact the [Flags] attribute only allows for power-of-two values to be assigned (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, etc.)

My **question** this time is simple - other than having a dictionary like `Dictionary<MotionDirection, int> directions`, or *constants* (I shudder at the thought), am I either forgetting, or ignorant of some C# language construct that can let me simply add two `MotionDirection`s together as if they were two `int`s?

Comment: The common way to do this is to use vectors.  If you only want a direction you can "ignore" the length / speed of a vector and always set them to 1 or some other constant.

Comment: That was the first way I tried to do it, but I hit mathematical problems when trying to express the direction 'Southwest' as the sum of 'South' and 'West', where the two vectors are Euler angles (South = [0 180 0], West = [0 135 0 ]; (South + West) * 0.5 = [0 225 0], which in that setup is *southeast*.

Comment: umm.. west is 270, 180+270/2 = 225 -- and 225 is southwest last I heard

Comment: In any case, using well understood math for this stuff is the way to go -- the whole assigning primes to directions makes no sense.  If you want to store it in a bit field you could assign powers of two, but you would still need to do a lookup to get the result.  Every decent graphics card will do all the calculations for you in hardware if you use standard 2d and 3d representations.

Comment: @Hogan I think the setup I was doing was a problem with that setup.  I had North = Vector3.forward = [0, 0, 0], East = [0 -90 0], West = [0 90 0], and South = [0 180 0].  In hindsight...I only wonder what precisely I was smoking.  I can't believe I thought that was a good idea.

Comment: As for bit fields, I hadn't found a good way to do that.  I guess I could do something like [North East South West], where North is 1000, Northeast is 1100, South East is 0110, etc...

Alternatively, I'm an idiot.  Would you make the bit field thing an answer?  I can't believe I didn't take the whole bit setup with directions to its logical conclusion.  I was halfway there the entire freaking time.

Comment: Bits? Where are you going to go for South + North?

Comment: I don't think bits is a good idea, but if you are making "code numbers" for things a bit field makes more sense than using primes.  Primes gets no value that I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it using two numbers between 0 and 360 (if you don't have such a function built into your graphics card):

```
 if a = b then 
   new_direction = a
 else      
   if a < b then 
     if (b-a < 180) then
       new_direction = (a + (b-a)/2) mod 360
     else
       new_direction = (b + (360 - b + a)/2) mod 360
   else
     if (a-b < 180) then
       new_direction = (b + (a-b)/2) mod 360 
     else
       new_direction = (a + (360 - a + b)/2) mod 360
```